# Block element not visible on page

Tags: html, css

Just started coding CSS and having issues with a  element (class is "strip") that seems to be invisible when I compile my code. If I set the position of the element to 'absolute' it seems to appear, however I need it to appear using 'relative' and this does not seem to be working.

The class of the div I am referring to is "strip", which at this point should appear as a red block in front of all other elements.

I've tried messing around with the z-index, but this hasn't seemed to change anything.

**CSS:**

```
.banner {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    height: 56px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: #C6C6C6;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}

.header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Titillium Web Regular", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    bottom: 58px;
}

.logo img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
    height: 50px;
    width: 44px;
    left: 3px;
    bottom: 114px;
}

.strip {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 5;
}

body {
    background-color: #d1e1ff;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
</head>

<body>

    <div class = banner>
    </div>

    <div class = header>
        <h1>club quiz<h1>
    </div>

    <div class = logo>
        <img src = "https://myuwastudentguild.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/UWA_Student_Guild_Corpo15A_Black.png"/>
    </div>

  <div class = strip>
  </div>

</body>
```

At this point, the  in the "strip" class should be appearing as a red block in front of all other elements, however it is instead invisible.

[Current Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5LaU.png)

[Desired Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nGYr.png)
Basically I'm just looking to add a panel that runs down the centre of the page

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with this code but your HTML code & Css doesn't look good at all.

Comment: @SumitPatel literally first time I've ever coded CSS or HTML. Just learning

Comment: Please add the design which you want to achieve that way we can help you to improve your current code.

Comment: @SumitPatel I've included a rough sketch of what I'm going for at the bottom of the question. I intend to eventually add content inside this panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Next to what Thanveer suggested**

What exactly happening is - when you have

> `position:absolute; height:100%`

it will occupy 100% of the screen and then you said `bottom:200px` so it will push this `div` from `(0,0)`(as it was absolute with respect to you body) to `(0, -200)`.  when you want this element to have

> `position:relative; height:100%`

it will occupy the 100% of the **parent** element, which is body in your case that doesn't have any height.

So solution is either define some fixed height on body

```
body
{
  background-color: #d1e1ff;
  margin: 0;
  height:500px;
}
```

**OR**

create parent wrapper on `.strip` and assign some height on that wrapper.

```
  ...
  ...
  <div style="height:100px">
    <div class="strip"></div>
  </div>
  ...
  ...
```

Remember as you are trying to use `position:relative;bottom: 200px;`. it will be the real position of the `.strip` element (x,y) and then it will be push upward by 200 px to position will be (x, y-200).

Check the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kd496cqj/1/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it to see using relative then all you have to do is give a fixed height inside your css

```
.strip {
    height:200px;
}
```

And you have used a lot of `position:relative` in your code which is not necessary. So please check out how positioning in CSS works. That could make things much easier for you.

Comment: Please mark my answer as useful if it helped you because that means a lot , Thanks mate

Comment: Unfortunately won't allow me to as I've just started and my reputation is too low. As soon as I'm able to I will. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use a fix `height` on class `strip`:

```css
.banner {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    height: 56px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: #C6C6C6;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}

.header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Titillium Web Regular", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    bottom: 58px;
}

.logo img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
    height: 50px;
    width: 44px;
    left: 3px;
    bottom: 114px;
}

.strip {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 5;
}

body {
    background-color: #d1e1ff;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
</head>

<body>

    <div class = banner>
    </div>

    <div class = header>
        <h1>club quiz<h1>
    </div>

    <div class = logo>
        <img src = "https://myuwastudentguild.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/UWA_Student_Guild_Corpo15A_Black.png"/>
    </div>

  <div class = strip>
  </div>

</body>
```